# Does anyone use nothing but reference variables to increase efficency and decrease size?

Tags: c++, variables, reference

If some of you haven't noticed already, I'm a noob.  With that said, here is my question:

Do any of you experienced programmers use reference variables to decrease the memory required of your programs?  I was thinking that, while probably a dangerous practice, you could use reference variables for mobile applications to make them use less memory and make them faster.

I know that in C++ when you pass a variable, as an argument, to a function that it creates a copy of that variable, but you can use the & to make it a reference variable which just points to the variables memory location.  Wouldn't that make your program use less memory overall and make things faster?

Comment: What a about char (size == 1) versus a reference to char (size == 4 or 8 typically) ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this.

Comment: Your initial premise is wrong - you suggest that using references reduces memory usage, but passing a char by value requires 1 byte, whereas passing a char by reference requires an address (typically 4 or 8 bytes), not to mention a subsequent de-reference to get the value.

Comment: I get that part now that it's been explained, but all that is just passed.  Without passing a variable as a reference the program has to create a new variable in memory.  Does passing an address take up more memory and processing than creating a whole new variable in memory and remembering it's address?

Comment: It depends on the architecture and ABI, but typically values may be passed in registers and/or on the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For big things, like structs and objects a reference uses less memory. However most people already pass these by reference anyway so it doesn't matter for our discussion.
2. Smaller things like ints and chars are the same size or smaller then a reference. There is no memory gain by passing them by reference...
3. ... but there is a performance penalty, since referrences need to be dereferenced in order to manipulate the value.
4. Finally, pass by reference is more prone to bugs then pass-by-value. Programs should be build for correctness first and performance second.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't realize that there was a penalty for dereferencing.  I guess C++ does that in the background so I didn't even realize it was a step.

Comment: Great. I definitely should've written all the stuff below.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on (a) underlying architecture, (b) framework and (c) language you use, but the general answer is **no** - this is not the best (or even common) optimization practice and **yes** - programs may run slower (much slower!) using your approach.

Comment: Please explain exactly why a program might run "much slower" if you use references ?

Comment: Can you explain why they would run slower?  If you are skipping the step of creating a new variable, wouldn't that make it faster?

Comment: @PaulR: as I said, it depends on some things seriously. Considering x86 architecture without any stuff like CLR or JVM, using something like C or C++. You have a procedure and you need to pass a wchar_t to it, sizeof(wchar_t) = 1 byte. If you place value on the stack, you just need to write 1 byte and read 1 byte. If you place reference to it on the stack, you need to write 4 bytes (consider sizeof(MAddr) = 4), read 4 bytes and perform an indirect read from the address specified by these 4 bytes.

Comment: Next example. Is it a good idea to make a member class instances of the class linked to the container or instantiated in it? If you want to instantiate, you do "ClassName objactName" and specify the constructor in the containter constructor, otherwise you do "ClassName* objectRef" and use "new ClassName(...)". The answer is first option is better for the compiler, since it can generate offsets for members' members in compile-time (for example, when it performs accessors inlining).

Answer (score 0):

In C variables are passed by value by default and there is no advantage in most cases in passing by reference as you are still passing a value (It's just the pointer rather than the value it refers to). Keep in mind that a pointer to a byte will be bigger than the byte its self!

With more complex types such as arrays and structs C will pass them by reference by default. It is inefficient to create a copy of a struct to pass into a function unless the function needs its own copy of the structure for some reason.
If you want to pass by reference, but you are worried about the function changing your struct you can use the const keyword to ensure it cannot be changed (or at least not easily).